# GRXML grammar for number and letters sequences e.g. serial number

Tags: speech-recognition, grammar, voice-recognition

I ma trying to create a GRXML grammar in voice mode that will find a serial number in a text. here as an example of my attempt to find sequence of three digits followed by three letters:

```
<grammar 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" 
    xml:lang="en"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar
    http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/grammar.xsd"
    version="1.0"
    mode="voice"
    root="main"
    tag-format="semantics/1.0"
    >
    <rule id="main" scope="public">
        <ruleref special="GARBAGE"/>
        <item repeat="3">
            <ruleref uri="#digit"/>
            <tag>out = out + rules.digit;</tag>
        </item>
        <item repeat="3">
            <ruleref uri="#letter"/>
            <tag>out = out + rules.letter;</tag>
        </item>
        <ruleref special="GARBAGE"/>
    </rule>
    <rule id="letter">
        <one-of>
            <item>A</item>
            <item>B</item>
            <item>C</item>
            <item>D</item>
            <item>E</item>
            <item>F</item>
            <item>G</item>
            <item>H</item>
            <item>I</item>
            <item>J</item>
            <item>K</item>
            <item>L</item>
            <item>M</item>
            <item>N</item>
            <item>O</item>
            <item>P</item>
            <item>Q</item>
            <item>R</item>
            <item>S</item>
            <item>T</item>
            <item>U</item>
            <item>V</item>
            <item>W</item>
            <item>X</item>
            <item>Y</item>
            <item>Z</item>
        </one-of>
    </rule>
    <rule id="digit">
        <one-of>
            <item>0<tag>out="0";</tag></item>
            <item>Zero<tag>out="0";</tag></item>
            <item>1<tag>out="1";</tag></item>
            <item>One<tag>out="1";</tag></item>
            <item>2<tag>out="2";</tag></item>
            <item>Two<tag>out="2";</tag></item>
            <item>3<tag>out="3";</tag></item>
            <item>Three<tag>out="3";</tag></item>
            <item>4<tag>out="4";</tag></item>
            <item>Four<tag>out="4";</tag></item>
            <item>5<tag>out="5";</tag></item>
            <item>Five<tag>out="5";</tag></item>
            <item>6<tag>out="6";</tag></item>
            <item>Six<tag>out="6";</tag></item>
            <item>7<tag>out="7";</tag></item>
            <item>Seven<tag>out="7";</tag></item>
            <item>8<tag>out="8";</tag></item>
            <item>Eight<tag>out="8";</tag></item>
            <item>9<tag>out="9";</tag></item>
            <item>Nine<tag>out="9";</tag></item>
        </one-of>
    </rule>
</grammar>
```

The problem with this grammar is that it needs white spaces or other delimiters (like comma or full stop) between every character. This means that will detect only sequences like this `1 2 3 A B C`, but not when characters touch each other e.g. `12 3 A B C`. I am testing this with Microsoft Speech SDK. How can I update the grammar that it will find what I want? Thank you.

Comment: Add 12, twelve and other numbers.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev that is not a solution to add millions of all possible combinations

Comment: Not really millions. You need "twenty" and others, "twelve" and others, "hundred" and "thousand" and that is it. About 30 words total.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I would need to add every possible combination of where the white space will and will not be including all combinations for case with no whites spaces i.e. from 000AAA to 999ZZZ which alone is more then 17 millions of combinations.

Comment: You are too scared counting variants. Try to recognize first and postprocess  in the code, not in the grammar. There is no real need to play with tags to return you exact serial number, you can use code to convert recognition result to a serial number.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Problem is that I cannot post process the result in code. I would love to use just a regular expression, but this is for a black box system, which accepts GRXML grammars only and there is no way to interact with the results of recognition.

Comment: My condolences then, there are many setups around which are much more flexible.